# python write-to-file issue, cannot understand behavior

Tags: python-2.7

**Env**: Python 2.7

I write some code that write list terms into text files.

Windows sublime remote connected to ubuntu server to edit files

**Behavior**:

I use **file cmd** to see the property of the text file, find something interesting.

I guess it could be "**xx.txt UTF-8 Unicode text**",

but actually it is "**xx.txt: DOS executable (COM)**"

By mistake I use with clause and f.close() method at the same time. I cannot understand behavior that happens.

**Code**:

```
with open(output, 'w') as f:
    for comment in sample_list:
        f.write(comment + '\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: What does the file *actually* contain when you write to it? `file` might be confused by some data in the header, potentially a string such as `MZ`.

Comment: This might sound stupid but is your `f.close()` not in the with loop?

Comment: The `f.close()` is unneeded - the whole point of the `with open(...` construct is that the file is guaranteed to be closed, no matter how that block is exited.